# Audio Streaming App using Android MediaPlayer starts failing to stream after weeks of flawless working

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a streaming app. Although I have been working with java for a long time, I am new to Android and not finding it straightforward.
First of all, using Android Media player worked alright until some weeks later, it stopped working. I contacted the streaming agent, they explained that they changed nothing and further added that it is an encoding problem which leaves me confused. So why did it work before?

The recommendation is to use AAC encoder. I don't know how to go about using an encoder in Mediaplayer...
The streaming link is a playlist.m3u8 format.
Anyone who can help me out? I would really like to know why the App stopped streaming in the first place.

```
package com.example.yoyojojo.first_streaming;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private Button buttonPlay;
private Button buttonStop;
private String url = "http://aztecalive-lh.akamaihd.net/i/0qeij0bji_1@26639/index_2_av-b.m3u8";        //I am having problems with this type of links .m3u8
private String url2 = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio2_mf_p";
private String url3 = "http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138";


private RadioGroup radioStation;
private RadioButton selectedStation;
private RadioButton editStation;
private TextView text;
private EditText newUrlEntry;

private CharSequence bbc = "BBC", usa = "Shoutcast USA", guru = "GuruMP3";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    radioStation = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioStation);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    newUrlEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


    editStation = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.editStation);


    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId = radioStation.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selectedStation = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String choice = selectedStation.getText().toString();

            text.setText("Station: "+choice);
            String streamUrl = "";

            switch(choice) {
                case "BBC":
                    streamUrl = url2;
                        break;
                case "Shoutcast USA":
                    streamUrl = url3;
                        break;
                case "GuruMP3":
                    streamUrl = url;
                    break;
                case "Enter URL":
                    streamUrl = newUrlEntry.getText().toString();
                    text.setText("Station: "+streamUrl.substring(0, 10));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is the error being generated:

```
06-21 18:00:17.116 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 D/Starting: Starting Streaming
06-21 18:00:20.218 18668-18681/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
06-21 18:00:20.218 18668-18681/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
06-21 18:00:20.218 18668-18681/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
06-21 18:00:20.218 18668-18681/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
06-21 18:00:20.218 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 D/Starting: Prepare failed.: status=0x64
06-21 18:00:20.221 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9fd96d40)
06-21 18:00:20.221 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
06-21 18:00:20.222 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 185 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 18:00:20.223 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
06-21 18:00:20.223 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
06-21 18:00:20.231 18668-18668/com.example.yoyojojo.appstream2 E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: Can you share code and also the mpd file if possible?

Comment: i have altered the real code while trying to find the problem. However, the above is the template I worked with. At first, the .m3u8 link above works, but now, it does not anymore. The other links work.

Comment: That helps - the stream itself seems fine. Can you also show the logcat output from your app when the playback fails?

Comment: ok, here is the error. This is almost running me nuts